# Animate UIView with constraints after it was added programmatically

Tags: ios, animation, constraints

I have an UIView that I add programmatically to my UIViewController like this:

```
if let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? MyView
    {
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //Horizontal orientation
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[view]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":myView]))
    }
```

Thats fine, the view is added with the needed space on left and right at (0,0) of the view controller.

What I want to achieve is that the view animates in from the bottom of the view controller to the center, and later animates out from center to top.
So first of all I tried to animate it to center from it's current position (0,0)

So what I did is:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
                   animations:
    {
        let center = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(0.0))
        self.view.addConstraint(center)
    })
```

Well the view is in the center but it is not animated. It directly jumps to it.

I searched and found a lot of answers that say I have to set the constant of the constraint and then call `layoutIfNeeded()` but all this examples use references to constraints that were set before as an IBOutlet, which I do not have as I add my view programmatically.

How can I animate the view properly, from bottom to center then center to top?

Thank you already!

Greetings

**EDIT 1**

Okay I'm going a bit further and explain what I want to achieve.
On my view controller, after a 5 second timer that is displayed to the user,  I want to show several questions, one after the other.

I want a question to slide in from bottom to center, been answered and then slide out from center to top. Then the next question comes in from bottom to center, is answered slides out and so on.

So after a 5 second timer I call method named slideInQuestion that creates a Question and animates it in:

```
func slideInQuestion()
{
    let question:QuestionView = createQuestion()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
                   animations:
    {
        self.yConstraint?.constant = CGFloat(0.0)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

The createQuestion method instantiates the question view and assigns the constraints to it

```
func createQuestion() -> QuestionView
{
    if let questionView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("QuestionView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? QuestionView
    {
        self.view.addSubview(questionView)
        questionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //Horizontal orientation
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[view]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":questionView]))
        yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: questionView,
                                              attribute: .centerY,
                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: self.view,
                                              attribute: .centerY,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        self.view.addConstraint(yConstraint!)
        return questionView
    }
    return QuestionView()
}
```

Before, I defined the yConstraint as an Instance variable as suggested by Duncan C like this:

```
    var yConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?
```

So what I expect what I have right now is:

The question view is created, it's center is on the center of the view controller + the height of the screen. That makes it outside of the visible view on bottom of the screen. Then it slides within 1 second from this position to centerY (0.0) of the screen.

But what it does right now, is sliding from top of the screen to the centerY of the screen and also at the same time it resizes to the margins of left and right like it is set in the first constraint

```
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[view]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":questionView]))
```

I'm totally confused right now I hope my explanation helps and someone has an idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Why does programmatic versus IBOutlet matter? Set your pre-animation constraints however you want, then set your post-animation constraints however you want, and call `layoutIfNeeded` inside an animation block when you want them to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I don't know how your View is created from your bundle, I've hacked together a quick example based of your code.

The key is that `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` is called twice. Once after the view is added and the second time in the animation block. And the modification of the constraint is not within the animation block.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var yConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.createView()

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.yConstraint?.constant = 32
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }

    func createView(){

        let questionView = UIView()
        questionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: questionView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.bounds.height-64)
        questionView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

        self.view.addSubview(questionView)

        questionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //Horizontal orientation
        self.view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[view]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":questionView]))

        yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: questionView,
                                         attribute: .top,
                                         relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: self.view,
                                         attribute: .top,
                                         multiplier: 1,
                                         constant: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        self.view.addConstraint(yConstraint!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed the problem was that I had to call layoutIfNeeded twice. Once after adding the view to the controller and then in the animation block.
Learned something today, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a constraint and save it in an instance variable. Then when you want to animate it, change the constant on the constraint and call layoutIfNeeded from the animation block just like you would for animating a storyboard-based constraint.

In your case, don't use `let constraint = ...` inside your function. Instead, use:

```
var centerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

In viewWillAppear:

```
centerConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, 
  attribute: .centerY, 
  relatedBy: .equal, 
  toItem: self.view, 
  attribute: .centerY,  
  multiplier: 1,  
  constant: CGFloat(0.0))
self.view.addConstraint(center)
```

And when you want to animate:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
                   animations:
    {
       centerConstraint.constant = newValue  //(Your value here.)
       myView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, yes you're right it must been to late already yesterday. 
Indeed I can store the constraint in a variable.

But I still have problems. I have to add multiple  comments otherwise I don't have enough characters to explain, sorry.

Comment: I put my constraint like
yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView,
                                                  attribute: .centerY,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: self.view,
                                                  attribute: .centerY,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
            self.view.addConstraint(yConstraint!)

Comment: And update it like
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
                       animations:
        {
            self.yConstraint?.constant = CGFloat(0.0)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

But then, it slides in from top, why? And not alone that it also resizes the left and right border from the first constraint I set (you can see it in the first post, the one that keeps the margin to left and right). 
I'm sorry the longer I think about that the more confused I get.
Calling layoutIfNeeded on myView instead of self.view has no effect, it only resizes from left and right

Comment: Don't put code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question to add your new code at the end, including the details of how and when you add the constraints in the first place.

Comment: And don't add constraints in the animation block. You should set up your view with pre-animation constraints, then return so the view is added to the view hierarchy and the pre-animation constraints can be applied. Again, edit your question to show how the original constraints are set up, and how the animation is invoked.

Comment: Ok, sorry I wasn't aware of that. 
I edited my question let me know if it is better now.

Thanks!